# wireless not working after installing Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, lubuntu

after i installed lubuntu my wifi is not working.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 25 May 2015 17:02 IST +0530

Booted last: 25 May 2015 16:38 IST +0530

Script from: 21 May 2015 09:10 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:12 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

"wireless-info.txt" 380 lines, 11905 characters
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command there.